# How to show no values exist in inequality

Tags: real-analysis

Find all real number values that satisfy the inequality

|x + 2| + |x - 1| < 2

I know such values do not exist but how would go about proving this?

I was thinking of using a proof by contradiction and saying something like

Assume:

|x + 2| + |x - 1| >= 2

And if that is undeniable true, then the original is false.

Not sure if this is correct

Comment: One way to tackle this problem is to distinguish three cases : first $x \leq -2$, secondly $-2 < x < 1$, and finally $x \geq 1$. For each of these cases, the equation simplifies and you can prove easily that it has no solution.

Comment: Consideer three cases : $1)$ $x<-2$ , $2)$ $-2\le x\le 1$ , $3)$ $x>1$

Comment: Intuitive approach : The left side gives the sum of the distances of a real number from the numbers $-2$ and $1$. $-2$ and $1$ have distance $3$, hence the sum of the distances must be at least $3$ , hence greater than $2$.

Comment: No cases necessary. Just use triangle inequality. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have according to triangle inequality

$$|x + 2| + |x - 1| = |x + 2| + |1  - x |\geq |x+2 + 1-x |= 3$$

So, there is no $x \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $|x + 2| + |x - 1| <2$.

Comment: This was one of my idea's so ill be using this, thanks to everyone else that answered

Answer (score 1):

Well, your statement of "proof by contradiction" applied to this problem is correct, but since you've only used a fully general proof technique, you must be missing the specific insight.

The no-thought way to do questions about absolute values is to consider the expression on every different interval where the absolute values differ. For example, you can consider the four cases $x + 2 (\geq, <) 0$ and $x - 1 (\geq, <) 0$. (One of those four cases actually doesn't happen.)

Answer (score 1):

picture two functions:
$$f(x)=|x+2|,g(x)=|x-1|$$
$f$ has a minima at $(-2,0)$ and $g$ has a minima at $(1,0)$. Now say $h=f+g$, and look at three separate domains:
$$h(x)=\begin{cases}-(2x+1)&x\le-2\\3&-2<x<1\\2x+1&x\ge1\end{cases}$$
over the first part of the domain the minima occurs at $x=-2$ where $h=3$ then for $-2<x<1$, $h=3$ then for $x\ge 1$ the mima occurs at $x=1$ where $h=3$. So the minimum value of the function is $3$ and hence there is no positive domain over which the inequality is true

Answer (score 1):

Due to $$|x-a|=\begin{cases}
x-a, &\text{ if } x \geqslant a\\
a-x, &\text{ if } x \leqslant a\\
\end{cases}$$
we have 3 cases for the left-hand side:

$$|x+2|+|x-1|=\begin{cases}
-2-x+1-x, &\text{ if } x \leqslant -2\\
x+2+1-x, &\text{ if } -2 \leqslant x \leqslant 1\\
x+2+x-1, &\text{ if } x \geqslant 1\\
\end{cases}$$
For each case it's straight forward to show that the left hand side is 3 at least.

Or you can plug in the condition, for example in the 1st case $x\leqslant -2$ we get:
$$|x+2|+|x-1| \stackrel{x\leqslant -2}=-2-x+1-x = -2x-1 < 2$$
from which we infer $x>3/2$ which cannot be due to $x\leqslant -2$.

Comment: Does emacs really drive you nuts?