# Solving inequalities with two absolute values

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

This is my first question on this site so apologize for formatting and such.
I have the following inequality:

$$ -5 \le | x + 2 | - | x - 3 | \le  5$$

I'm confused as to the order or precedence of what to solve. Should I solve $-5 \le | x + 2 |$, then $ - | x - 3 | \le 5 $?

If it were $ -5 \le | x + 2 | - | x - 3 |$  then I can see how the solution is the distance between $ x$ and $ 2$ and $ x$ and $3$.

Comment: Consider then cases $x <-2, -2 \leq x <3$ and $x \geq 3$.

Comment: $−5≤|+2|−|−3|≤5$ is a shorthand for "$−5≤|+2|−|−3|$ and $|+2|−|−3|≤5$".

Comment: $|x+2|$ is not the distance between $x$ and $2$. It's the distance between $x$ and $-2$.

Comment: Apart from some constants, the question / solution is the same like for https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4433749/how-to-show-no-values-exist-in-inequality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle the 3 cases
$$|x+2|-|x-3|=\begin{cases}
+(x+2)-(x-3), &\text{ if } x \geqslant 3 \\
+(x+2)+(x-3), &\text{ if } -2 \leqslant x \leqslant 3 \\
-(x+2)+(x-3), &\text{ if } x \leqslant -2 \\
\end{cases}$$
separately.  For example, the 2nd case leads to

$-5\leqslant 2x -1 \leqslant 5 $

$-4\leqslant 2x \leqslant 6 $

$-2\leqslant x \leqslant 3 $

provided $-2\leqslant x \leqslant 3$ holds true.

Answer (score 1):

Here we can use the fact that $|x-a|$ is distance from point $x$ to point $a$ on numbered line.

Then $-5\leq |x+2|-|x-3|\leq 5$ means that distance from $x$ to $-2$ and from $x$ to $3$ must differ not greater than by 5. Distance between $-2$ and $3$ is exactly $5$, so **this inequality holds for every $x$** because of triangle inequality $AB+BC \geq AC$, where $AB$ is smaller of $|x+2|$ and $|x-3|$, $AC$ is greater of $|x+2|$ and $|x-3|$, $BC=5$.